# How to fix “WARNING: overwriting environment variables set in the machine overwriting variable ‘PATH’ " error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I activate my Python environment it says

```
WARNING: overwriting environment variables set in the machine overwriting variable [‘PATH’].
```

I also noticed because of this most of the commands I use within the environment including jupyter notebook don’t work. This problem started when I made a mistake while integrating another software which I now successfully have integrated.

To reproduce it I open up **Anaconda Prompt** then within the terminal I activate my environment with `conda activate bash1pilot`. When it’s activated I can tell there is a problem not just because of the warning message but also because the commands thereafter don’t work properly such as jupyter notebook which is the program I’m trying to access.

When it's working it's supposed to direct me to **Jupyter-Notebook** when I do the command but when I run `jupyter notebook`, it doesn't work because of the error.

In addition to this, it was working perfectly until I was trying to integrate a different program but I made a mistake during the integration process which likely led me to this problem. If I had to guess it could be a directory issue. If I were to retrace my steps this is what I remember doing:

```
conda activate bash1pilot
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\User\Desktop\gmsh-4.11.1-Windows64
```

then I closed and reopened Anaconda

Comment: you changed the PATH variable, you should always try to avoid directly modifying the PATH variable within your Conda environment. I dunno how to fix it, i would try to reinstall the software

Comment: If I reinstall the software would I lose my existing environment and saved code in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Things that say "WARNING" are, by definition, *not errors*.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the code somewhere else just in case.

Download the env setup file so that you can recreate the env with the same dependencies later on:

```
conda activate myenv
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Once reinstalled recreate it with the setup file:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Also check the environment.yml, it could have the PATH variable changed so just in case open the file in a text editor and remove or comment out any lines that modify it.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling Anaconda while also backing up my .ipynb files fixed the issue. I created a new environment and will try to do what I was attempting earlier this time avoiding the mistakes I previously made by modifying the 'path' variable.  Thank you Shodan4004 your suggestion worked.

Comment: Please read [answer] and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.